# PHP session not persistent without cookies

Tags: php, apache, session

With disabled cookies in the browser,  the sessions on our webserver are  not
persistant. That means, if I go forward to the next page, I receive a new
session ID. On every page I reload I become a new session ID.
With enabled cookies everting is fine.

Specifcations of the Webserver:

- PHP version 5.3.3
- Apache version 2.2.13
- Webserver with SUSE Linux

Locally on my XAMPP installation everything works.

## Update:

I have following settings on each page:

- ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
- ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '1');
- session_start();

The session ID is present in the URI, but when I check the session ID on the page their is a new ID and with each reload their is an other ID.

Comment: As others have said.  HTTP is stateless so you need a mechanism to pass this context (commonly known as the SID) from one request to the next in the session.  The std approach is to accept *both* the cookie and request parameter sid.  Also if the current request had no cookies set, then to add a sid=XXX as a parameter to all site links which need session context.  *However*, this has the downside that unknowing users can their post session links -- seen this done many a time on a forum.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course. Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, the session is linked to the user by storing the session ID in a cookie. Deleting (or refusing) this cookie will end your session.

Comment: there is a reason most sites scream at you to turn your cookies back on if you want to log in ^_^

Comment: Have a look at Álvaro's answer, this is what you need to do if you can't use cookies. This is not recommended, though (as he notes as well).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want cookies, you have to transmit the session ID in the URL:

> Unless you are using PHP 4.2.0 or later, you need to enable it
>   manually when building PHP. Under Unix, pass --enable-trans-sid to
>   configure. If this build option and the run-time option
>   `session.use_trans_sid` are enabled, relative URIs will be changed to
>   contain the session id automatically.

http://es.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

See also `session.use_cookies` and `session.use_only_cookies`.

This method makes it particularly easy to give away your private data just sharing a link so almost nobody uses it nowadays.

Comment: I tried the Script from your link with the counter. But it is the same, with cookies works and without cookies don't work. For us the website must also work without cookies.

Comment: If you don't understand the information provided in any answer, feel free to ask for clarifications. But please don't repeat the same question again and again while suggesting that all you want is ready-to-use code you can paste into your site.